# Change of variable in an $L^\infty$ norm

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, partial-derivative

Let $a>0$, $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $f_a\in  C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$ defined by
$$
f_a(x):= f\left(\frac{x}{a}\right).
$$
Denoting by $B_s$ the ball of center $0\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and radius $s$.

Is it the $L^\infty$ norm of $\Delta f_a$ on $B_a$ equal to $a^{-2}\|  \Delta f  \|_{L^\infty (B_1)  }$ or $\|  \Delta f  \|_{L^\infty (B_1)  }$ ?

More precisely,
$$
\| \Delta f_a  \|_{L^\infty (B_a)  }=
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
  a^{-2}\|  \Delta f  \|_{L^\infty (B_1)  }
\\[4pt]
or
\\[4pt]
 \|  \Delta f  \|_{L^\infty (B_1)  }
\end{aligned}
\right. \qquad ?
$$

My confusion become from how can I handle the $\Delta$ operator.

I tried the following:
$$ \Delta f_a (x) = \Delta f\left(\frac{x}{a}\right),$$
so doing the change of variable $u=\frac{x}{a}$ I got
$$  \Delta f\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) = \Delta f(u),$$
and considering that if $x=a$ then $u=1$, and then I concluded
$$
\|  \Delta f_a  \|_{L^\infty (B_a)  } =  \|  \Delta f  \|_{L^\infty (B_1)  }.
$$

Is it correct ?

Comment: Why are you in doubt? Have you tried an example? Say $d=1$, $f(x) = x^2$?

Comment: @cs89 I tried but I am really confused in fact

Comment: Why? You should probably give more details on why you are puzzled so that we can help you better.

Comment: The fact that $\| f \|_{L^{\infty}} = \lim_{p \to \infty} \|f\|_{L^p}$ may be useful here.

Comment: @cs89 when I did the computations I got both answers, but I don't what is wrong with one of them

Comment: You should probably show us these computations, in particular the one that gives $\|\Delta f_a\|_{L^\infty(B_a)} = \| \Delta f \|_{L^\infty(B_1)}$ so that we can examine it.

Comment: @cs89 I agreed details above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mistake in your computation when you write $\Delta f_a(x) = \Delta f(\frac x a)$, which stems from incorrect parenthesis / priorization of operations.

Let us go slowly. You start from you function $f$, from which you define a new function $f_a$, which occurs to be defined by $f_a(x) = f(\frac x a)$. Now you want to compute the Laplacian of $f_a$, $\Delta f_a$ and evaluate it at some point $x$, so you want $(\Delta f_a)(x)$. *As a side note, computing $\Delta (f_a(x))$ would not really make sense since $f_a(x)$ is a (fixed) real number, and not a function.*

Now, let us compute $\Delta f_a = \partial_{x_1}^2 f_a + \dotsb + \partial_{x_d}^2 f_a$. One way to make things clear is that $f_a = f \circ \sigma$ where $\sigma(x) = \frac{x}{a}$. By the chain rule
$$\partial_{x_i} f_a = \partial_{x_i} (f \circ \sigma)
= (\partial_{x_i} \sigma) ((\partial_{x_i} f) \circ \sigma)
= \frac 1 a (\partial_{x_i} f) \circ \sigma
$$
Differentiating once more and summing over $i$, you obtain $\Delta f_a = \frac{1}{a^2} (\Delta f) \circ \sigma$. So the correct version is indeed
$$
\| \Delta f_a \|_{L^\infty(B_a)} = \frac 1 {a^2} \| \Delta f \|_{L^\infty(B_1)}.
$$

Heuristically, when $a$ is small, you are "concentrating" your function. Such scalings make the derivatives larger, since the function must vary of the same amplitude but on shorter scales. So it is normal to have a $a^{-2}$ factor here for second-order derivatives.

Comment: A beautiful answer, I learned something important today. Thanks a million !